# Connect IBM database using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, db2, odbc

I tried connect IBM database through PDO using below code. But, it is not working

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=hostname;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;", "username", "password");
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($db);
    exit;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I got below error for the same

```
SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I have also added below code in php.ini file

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_ibm.dll
extension=php_ibm_db2.dll
```

Could anyone suggest me, how I can connect with IBM database?

Answer (score 0):

[The DSN prefix for DB2 databases is `ibm:`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.connection.php), not `odbc:`. Try changing that.

Here is the example connection string given in the documentation:

```
$db = new PDO("ibm:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=testdb;" .
  "HOSTNAME=11.22.33.444;PORT=56789;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;", "testuser", "tespass");
```

Comment: I have also tried that but I got an error 'could not find driver'. Could you please suggest me, How I can install drivers?

Comment: I tried db2_connect() but it returns an error 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function db2_connect() '

Comment: @JimeshGajera, I see that you've enabled the `php_pdo_ibm.dll` extension, but does that file actually exist in your extensions directory?

Comment: Yes, I have added those files in extensions directory

Comment: @JimeshGajera, "[the DB2 Client v9.1 or later must be installed on the same system as PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.php)". Do you have that installed?

Comment: @JimeshGajera, did you ever solve this? Did you have the DB2 Client v9.1 or later installed on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

there is different driver name for some computer, this is the list of driver you can try:

- DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};
- DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};

and try to use `System` instead of `HOSTNAME`

```
DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};DATABASE=BLUDB;System=hostname;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;
```

oh, and I'm using `DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};`