# php PDO ODBC DB2 construct

Tags: php, pdo, db2, odbc

I am having trouble constructing a PDO. It's a function I've never used before. Let's say these are my connection variables

```
$database = "BLUDB";
$hostname = "dashdb-enterprise-FAKE.services.dal.bluemix.net"; 
$user     = "fakeuser";   
$password = "fakepsw";   
$port     = 50000;          
$driver  = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};";
$dsn     = "DATABASE=$database; " .
       "HOSTNAME=$hostname;" .
       "PORT=$port; " .
       "PROTOCOL=TCPIP; " .
       "UID=$user;" .
       "PWD=$password;";
$conn_string = $driver . $dsn;
```

I have tried this:

```
$conn = new PDO( "DB2:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER},HOSTNAME=dashdb-enterprise-FAKE.services.dal.bluemix.net,PORT=50000,DATABASE=BLUDB,PROTOCOL=TCPIP,UID=fakeuser,PWD=fakepsw");
```

and a few other permutations. But I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /home/robur12/domains/idobczyce.pl/public_html/mike/dava/index.php:41 Stack trace: #0 /home/robur12/domains/idobczyce.pl/public_html/mike/dava/index.php(41): PDO->__construct('DB2:DRIVER={IBM...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/robur12/domains/idobczyce.pl/public_html/mike/dava/index.php on line 41
```

I have followed the process as described here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRBY/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_connecting_php.html

I have completed the instalation and I have even run the validation command in shell

db2cli validate -dsn DashDB -connect -user bluadmin -passwd 'your_secret_password'

see output below

[image]

I am running under Linux s90.linuxpl.com 4.4.27-grsec #1 SMP Tue Oct 25 20:38:40 CEST 2016 x86_64

my php.ini only says

```
extension=odbc.so
```

in the web browser `phpinfo();`  will return

```
'./configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php7.3' '--disable-debug' '--disable-ipv6' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ctype' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-inline-optimization' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-session' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--with-bz2' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php7.3' '--with-pear=/usr/local/php7.3/lib/php' '--with-curl=/usr/local/lib' '--with-freetype-dir' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-gd' '--with-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-iconv=/usr/local' '--with-imap-ssl' '--with-imap=/usr/lib/' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-kerberos' '--with-ldap' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-openssl=/usr/local/adds/openssl' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--with-pspell' '--with-readline' '--with-tidy' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xsl' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib' '--enable-opcache' '--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql' '--with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql' '--enable-intl' '--with-pdo-odbc=ibm-db2,/usr/local/adds/dsdriver'
```

but when I run `php -m` in the command line I do NOT see ibm_db2 and I do NOT see pdo_ibm. I only see the following:

[image]

I have contacted my php server provider and asked then:

"can you possibly instal the following php modules: pdo_ibm and ibm_db2?"

and they replied:

"it seems you are trying to access IBM DB2.

you should be using the PDO function following the instructions here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

we have compiled pdo ibm_db2 for you on Friday.
PDO Driver for ODBC (ibm-db2) => enabled
if you require other modules to be installed please provide a link or documentation"

Comment: Have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633233/connect-ibm-database-using-pdo - especially some of the comments about what needs to be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out tying `php -m` in the shell command line accessed my php 7.2 modules.

I needed to type `/usr/local/php7.3/bin/php -m` to view my php 7.3 modules.

when I did that I saw 2 additional modules: PDO and PDO_ODBC.

and the php PDO function syntax I had to use was:

```
$database = 'BLUDB';
$username = 'fakeusername';
$password = 'fakepassword';
$hostname = 'dashdb-fakehostname.bluemix.net';
$port = 50000;

$string= sprintf("odbc:DRIVER{PDO_ODBC};DATABASE=%s;HOSTNAME=%s;PORT=%d;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;",
     $database ,
     $hostname ,
     $port);

$connection = new PDO($string,$username,$password)
```

Comment: This works to me, I have to make use of the `odbc:` preffix.

Answer (score 1):

For some driver versions, you need to specify the prefix `ibm:` to use the IBM pdo extension for Db2.

Additionally there are several prerequisites that need to be installed and configured first. It helps to verify each prerequisite separately before you attempt a connection. You should install the php-cli for your version of PHP to help with problem determination (for example php7.0-cli).

In particular, verify at the shell command line (on the hostname that runs PHP) that `php -m` shows both pdo_ibm and ibm_db2 are loaded. If one or both are missing then either your php.ini is not configured, or the driver is not loading (in which case you should see an error message at the start of the `php -m` output.

Here is an example showing a full connection string instead of a catalogued database:

```
<?php

#
# This shows using a connection-string to a Db2-on-cloud database.
#
# Prerequisites:
# 0. Follow IBM's documenation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/c0054947.html
# 1. Modules ibm_db and pdo_ibm are already installed to match the PHP
# 2. The php.ini loads the ibm_db and pdo_ibm drivers successfully 
# 3. You already verified your Db-client is operating successfully (use db2cli validate and db2cli validate -connect).
#


$database = 'bludb';
$user = 'whatever';
$password = 'whatever';
$hostname = 'dashdb-txn-sbox-whatever.bluemix.net';
$port = 50000;

$string= sprintf("ibm:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=%s;HOSTNAME=%s;PORT=%d;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;",
         $database ,
         $hostname ,
         $port);

try {
  $connection = new PDO(
         $string,$user,$password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

        $req=$connection->query("select * from syscat.views where viewschema not like 'SYS%' and viewschema not like 'IBM%'");
        foreach ($req as $row) {
                print_r($row);
        }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi Mao, thank you. I am now getting the "could not find driver" on my web page.  I have already installed IBM drivers, which YOU confrimed on another case I logged 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891018/connecting-php-server-to-db2-from-outside-ibm-cloud
any ideas please?

Comment: thank you again for getting back to me. This issue is not my domain but I do need to solve it. If you could please tell me what I need to do / deliver I would love to do it. I just dont' know what commands to run in the command line. As you can see in the other issue on stack I am able to connect to my db from the command line but not via web browser. If you could possible tell me what to do I will follow your instructions.

Comment: thank you for your help. I will do exactlly as you wrote but I need help from my server admin... he'll be available on Monday... so I will get back to this on Monday. Thank you again and have a great weekend.

Comment: hello Mao. I did my best to provide the details you asked for. If possible, could you please take a look and let me know what you think, please.

Comment: @MikePala If the supplied information is correct, then your PHP environment does not have the required modules loaded to support *any* interface to Db2.  Until you get those modules loaded (visible in `php -m` output), then you will be unable to use PHP to communicate with Db2.  This is out of scope for stackoverflow because it is  configuration work . You need to get a skilled person onsite who can build the required modules from source (if they are unavailable precompiled for your Linux), and install them, and configure and test each of them, and get them working with Db2.

Comment: Mao, thank you so much. your help with this is incredible. I have contacted my php server provider. Could you please take a look at the short conversation I added to the case and tell me what you think or what should I tell them.